# A question about the d'Alembert ratio test for convergence.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

My question is about a detail in the d'Alembert ratio test for convergence. Suppose I have a series $\sum a_n$, if I take the limit $\lim \left |\dfrac{a_{n+1}}{a_n} \right|=L$ and $L>1$, it means $|a_{n+1}|>|a_n|$ for sufficient large $n$. Why then I can conclude the limit of $a_n$ is not zero?

Comment: Because $0 \le |a_n| < |a_{n+1}| < |a_{n+2}| < \ldots < |a_\infty|$ starting from this sufficient large $n$.

Comment: What if for some $n_0$ we have $a_{n_0}>0$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose we do have some sequence $\{ a_n \}$ that fulfills the property as described, i.e. $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}|\frac{a_{n + 1}}{a_n}| = L > 1$. With this assumption, we can choose some $\epsilon$-neighborhood of $L$ such that the the quotient $|\frac{a_{n + 1}}{a_n}| = \frac{|a_{n + 1}|}{|a_n|}$ is greater than one for some index $N$, $n \geq N$. In particular, from this we have $0 < |a_N| < |a_{N + 1}| < |a_{N +2}|...$ and so forth.

Note then, as seen in the definition of convergence, $a_n$ converges to $0$ iff $|a_n|$ converges to $0$. Consider with this the $\epsilon$-neighborhood of $0$ of radius $|a_{N}| > 0$. Here it is intuitive that we cannot get $|a_n|$ within this radius for $n \geq N$, and thus it cannot converge to $0$. Working this through the equivalency yields that it cannot be the case $a_n \rightarrow 0$.

Comment: actually $|a_N|$ can't be zero, right?

Comment: You're correct, I have edited it to reflect the simplification.